# Get all instances of Bean JSF

Tags: jsf, javabeans

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve ALL instances of a given `Bean` from the `FacesContext`. This includes that beans might be session scoped.

Or do I have to register them somewhere in instatiating and retrieve them again later?

The method from which I want to clal this funktionality will be triggered by a `@Schedule` and is for clearing all caches that are held somewhere in the application

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Or do i have to register them somewhere in instatiating and retrieve them again later?*

Yes, you have to.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    allBeans.add(this);
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
    allBeans.remove(this);
}
```

`allBeans` can be an injected application scoped bean.

Comment: Ok thanks :) Was just wondering if there was already a built in way by JSF